# VBA going down column to check for string value?

Tags: vba

```
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
      If c.Value = "StringIWant" Then
```

Hi i'm new to vba and this part of the code is giving me an error, I just want to go down column 1, and copy and paste a certain block of cells next to it if the string value matches. Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: Add `.Cells` after `Columns(1)` - though you probably don't need to loop through all cells and might consider finding the last row instead.

Comment: Looping over the Column is a grossly inefficient way to do this, even when modified to only search the used range.  Consider using `Application.Match` instead

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @BigBen, you really should limit the scope of your loop. Do you really need to loop through all 1 million + rows that exist in any given column? Or do you actually need to loop down to the last used row?

This is how you would a last row loop.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim c As Range, LR As Long
LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In ws.Range("A2:A" & LR)
    If c = "StringIWant" Then
        'Do What?
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```